# How to solve "'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am trying to run the app from **terminal** in Android Studio by typing `flutter run` but it is saying

```
'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Now I have installed all flutter SDK, changed the environment variable of the path to ***flutter/bin*** folder, restarted it but still not working.

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: after adding to environment variables, did you restart your android studio or cmd, or powershell, whichever you're using?

Comment: android studio and yes

Comment: one more thin when I run this `git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable` in my terminal the terminal worked but I can't do that for every project

Comment: please tell me @kartoon

Comment: I followed these [steps](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#get-the-flutter-sdk) and it worked for me. You need to check if environment variables are correctly placed or not. That's all I can say.

Comment: I did followed the same thing but still

Comment: go to you /path/flutter/bin and then execute your flutter command. Do this to post your "flutter doctor -v"

Comment: Thank you @ it worked out I found out that I didn't run the flutter doctor after installation so went to `flutter/bin` folder through terminal ran your command and came back to my directory and it worked fine

Comment: However in my case I did it under System Variables will it cause any problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Path was set temporarily and non permanently. Checking the official docs, you can get the answer:

Using **MacOS**:

- temporarily will be: export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
- permanently:

  - export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin"
  - source $HOME/.rc file
  - echo $PATH

Official [DOCS](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path)

Using **Windows**:

- From the Start search bar, enter ‘env’ and select Edit environment variables for your account.
- Under User variables check if there is an entry called Path

Official [DOCS](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows)

Answer (score 0):

You have to link between Android studio and flutter,dart. So you should go in android studio File->Settings->Dart and Flutter under Languages & Frameworks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPOs9.jpg)

Then you should do this for flutter[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw92V.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**IF THE COMMAND ISN'T RECOGNIZED ONLY IN ANDROID STUDIO BUT IS WORKING FROM THE CMD**

I tried all the solutions but nothings' working on my windows. Android Studio's terminal cannot 'find' the command flutter. Instead of wasting your time fixing this, I'd rather you run the commands from the Windows Command Prompt directly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after searching a lot.

Before downloading flutter from

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install

Disable your antivirus.

Then move the folder to C: and add the exception for the antivirus you are using.

Remember to add to ENV path:

```
C:\Windows\System32
C:\Program Files\Git
C:\flutter\bin
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).