# In flutter I'm facing error in android studio terminal in every command i was typing

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, terminal

***'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.***

I'm getting flutter error or anything error when in run any command in terminal in Android studio. I lookup all settings but didn't get any solution, I also changed terminal sdk but still getting same error.

Terminal Error Screen
[image]

Comment: looks like flutter is not in your PATH environment variable

Comment: `, I also changed terminal sdk but still getting same error` obviously you did not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62007415/12709358